# Change the response of core magento api /v1/products

Tags: magento2

I am getting an attribute set in the api response . I  do not want that response in the Api call . How to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to do so. Because `rest api` will always return all product's data and you can't change that without overwriting magento's core logic. If you want to fetch special field you can use `graphQL` if it's possible in your situation.